# Extending Lebesgue Measure to Borel Sets via route other than Caratheodory (e.g. with Monotone Class Theorem)?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Following Erhan Cinlar's book Probability and Stochastics, we have the Monotone Class Theorem which states that $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \subset \mathcal{D}$ whenever $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\pi-$system (closed under arbitrary intersection) and $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\lambda-$system $(\emptyset \in \mathcal{D},$ closed under set difference and increasing union).

An important corollary is that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures agreeing on a $\pi-$system $\mathcal{C}$, then they agree on $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, the $\sigma-$algebra generating $\mathcal{C}$.

In my first readthrough, I assumed the extension of the Lebesgue measure was given in this section, but as far as I can tell, it only discusses this uniqueness result (which states that the Lebesgue measure is unique by defining it on closed subintervals of $\mathbb{R}$ which forms a $\pi-$system).

In another well known book, Probability and Measure by Patrick Billingsley, they discuss the Caratheodory Extension theorem but make no mention of it being a unique extension (making me believe that the Monotone Class Theorem was introduced in Probability and Stochastics to ensure uniqueness of the extension).  However, in reading other references, I find that the Caratheodory Extension Theorem is often provided in stating that the extension is unique.

So my question is, are there ways to extend the Lebesgue measure, if defined on say the closed subintervals of $\mathbb{R}$, to all Borel sets, via some well known route other than the Caratheodory extension theorem?  I'm trying to understand how Probability and Stochastics can utilize the Lebesgue measure without first properly extending it, so I feel like I'm missing something.

My followup question is whether there are specific conditions to ensure a unique extension via Caratheodory, since it seems like some texts say it is unique and some say otherwise.

Comment: First of all what you call Monotone Class Theorem is the Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. Monotone Class Theorem  is something else. AS far as I know any book which deals with Carathedory extension Theorem also gives uniqueness under sigma finiteness.

Comment: You're right that the extension of Lebesgue measure (i.e. its existence as a measure on all Borel sets) is something that one needs in probability, and is nontrivial.  It appears to me that  Çinlar simply decided not to include the proof in his book, perhaps assuming that the reader would already be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives to the Lebesgue-Carateodory approach. There is [**Daniell's**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_integral) approach that starts with no measure theory at all. Measure theory can be obtained as a byproduct. At the end, you get the same integrable functions as with the LC approach. Daniell's approach however, can be modified slightly to build stochastic integration. **Shilov's** book in integration as well as **Riesz--Nagy's** book on functional analysis have a contruction of integration closer to Daniell's. A book by **Klaus Bichteler** (Integration theory: A functional approach) builds integration based on Daniell's idea too.